# Puppetising Sensu on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, puppet, apt-get, sensu

When running my puppet scripts to install Sensu I get this error:

```
Error: Could not update: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install sensu' returned 100: Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following NEW packages will be installed:
   sensu
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 145 not upgraded.
Need to get 22.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 64.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
   sensu
E: There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes
```

Effectively, it is failing when trying to run 'apt-get update' and 'apt-get install sensu'

However when I run these commands in the ubuntu terminal after it has been provisioned using vagrant the commands both work.

Comment: It looks like the GPG key for Sensu is incorrect or out of date, can you post a link to what your Puppet manifests look like? Are you using the official Sensu Puppet module?: https://github.com/sensu/sensu-puppet

Comment: I am using the official Sensu Puppet Module however things have been configured by others as well. I think the issue may be something to do with: 
https://github.com/sensu/sensu-puppet/blob/master/manifests/init.pp

 $repo_key_id              = '7580C77F'

Comment: Can you post up the puppet manifest you're using? With any real world data changed to dummy values.

Comment: It's been fixed by adding:

  **# run apt-get update
  exec { "apt-update":
    command => "/usr/bin/apt-get update"
  }**

  before:

  **package { 'sensu':
    ensure  => $sensu::version,
  }**

In the package.pp file from the sensu puppet module. Must be something to do with the Ubuntu version